# Why do computer games often have their own language settings?

Tags: language, gaming, international

Computer video games often have their own language settings in the menu, and sometimes even prompt me what language I want to play in when I start them up. I don't recall seeing such behavior in any other sort of computer program; my spreadsheet program doesn't have its own "Language" menu and my code editor didn't ask me what language I wanted to use it in when I started it for the first time. Instead they both used the settings I have set for my operating system.

Is there a reason for this other than legacy? Are game engines unable to read my operating system's language settings for some reason?

Comment: I think its really more that windows supports so many more languages than the games do, that there isn't really much of a choice other than to make it explicit that the game is controlling it. besides, lots of people play games only available in non-native languages.

Comment: Most applications would expect to work in the same language as your system. Games are often used for education or fun and due to there being a lot of spoken word interactions you may prefer the "native" language of the game rather than a potentially poorly translated and dubbed version.

Answer (score 2):

The question is founded on incorrect assumptions. Programs *do* have "Language" menus. Both small tools and large apps more often do have their own language menus than not.

> my spreadsheet program doesn't have its own "Language" menu

Mine does:

[image]

Actually, both of them do.

[image]

For example, MS Office ISOs always come in a specific language – if I sign in to VLSC and download an ISO of the English version, it will be in English, regardless of the OS settings, but I can *also* install Office language packs that can be switched directly through Word/Excel settings.

Your web browser also has a language setting; if you ever tried to install Firefox from its "full" installer you would have seen a huge list of "Firefox Setup.exe" download options, one for each language, and it also has language packs that can be selected from Firefox's settings screen. So does Chrome. In general, I've seen more programs that *do* have language settings than programs which don't.

(Often it's because not all translations are of the same quality. Games are not translated to all possible languages. There's no point in "reading the OS settings" if the game only comes in 5 languages total and the OS matches none of those.)

Comment: Not to mention that some games actually do this right. Command and Conquer: Tiberium Wars detects the language during install and you can change it by using custom. There's no way to change the language after it is installed, and it will only allow the languages it has a translation for, very similar to how firefox for example is handling it. So it really is a by game and by app basis.

Comment: "There's no way to change the language after it is installed" is extremely annoying on multi-user PCs... Also when the program uses the wrong way to detect language, like how older versions of Google Chrome (mid-2010s) used to guess language based on your *Regional Settings*, so if you wanted to have Chrome in English you had to change your date/time format to USA, install Chrome, then change back.

Comment: Oh, I know. The only way to get the right language is to remove the game and reinstall it with the right language selected. In the Steam version, this has been moved to a setting you can select before installing. Though, there you can validate the gamefiles to change it too. I do think that may be a reason why modern games don't have this option in the installer, but rather in-game itself. Because they come with a one-click installer.